# MySQL after inset and update trigger

Tags: mysql

I have a  table test1 with columns id,name,designation,salary.I want to insert every record into test2 which is inserted into test1 and also update the every record in test2 which is updated in test1

Comment: Okay, then google the create trigger syntax for mysql and have a try. It's not that hard.

Comment: actually am new to mysql this is much complicated when compared with MSSQL

Comment: Really? My impression is, that MySQL is overall much easier than SQL Server. And the manual is a thousand times better than that of SQL Server.

Comment: And being new to something does not excuse laziness. And you should learn how to ask a question. This link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @fancyPants, to be fair, the documentation for stored routines and triggers is the weakest part of the MySQL documentation. One has to read many unrelated pages to understand how to write triggers.

Comment: The best single page is probably https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @BillKarwin That's the exact page I suggested to google for in my first comment. And I still think that the MySQL documentation even for this part is still better than that of SQL Server. But doesn't matter here anymore, OP obviously just wants someone else to do the work for him, as you can tell by his comment beneath the answer. And as usual he found someone willing to give the fish, instead of teaching how to fish.

Comment: @fancyPants i didn't asked for the fish.i had asked just hook to catch the fish.did you find any after update trigger query in the document which u have send the link

Comment: I don't think I understood correctly what you are actually looking for. That's why I posted this link above: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two triggers one on update and one on insert haven't tested it yet but something like this will do.

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_row_added 
AFTER INSERT ON test1
FOR EACH ROW 
  UPDATE test2
      SET name=NEW.name, designation=NEW.designation,salary=NEW.salary
      WHERE id=NEW.id ;

CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum AFTER UPDATE ON test1
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.ts <> OLD.ts THEN  
            INSERT INTO test2 (name, designation,salary) 
            VALUES(NEW.name, NEW.designation,NEW.salary);
        END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: i don't want to insert records after update just i want to update records in test2